# How to test if an array contains any value from another array using Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an array:

```
   Const domesticAnimals = ['Chicken','lama','Donkey']
   Const wildAnimals =['lama','lion','elephant']
```

How do I test If any `wildAnimals`  is listed in `domesticAnimals` array?

I have tried

```
test('test If any wild animal is in the domestic animal list', async() =>{
expect(domesticAnimals ).toContain('lama')
}) //works perfectly

test('test If any wild animal is in the domestic animal list', async() =>{
expect(domesticAnimals ).toContain(wildAnimals) // does not work
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have TWO arrays:

```
const domesticAnimals = ['Chicken','lama','Donkey'];
const wildAnimals =['lama','lion','elephant'];
```

The plain JS way of testing if one array contains any values from the other would be:

```
domesticAnimals.some(domesticAnimal => wildAnimals.includes(domesticAnimal));
```

So to put this in a test, would be:

```
test('test If any wild animal is in the domestic animal list', () =>{
    expect(domesticAnimals.some(
        domesticAnimal => wildAnimals.includes(domesticAnimal)
    )).toBe(true);
});
```

As a side-note, you marked the test functions as `async` but don't actually `await` anything, so the `async` is redundant.